# OpenGL wireFrame render of a OBJ file

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, wireframe, wavefront

I am writing a program that just needs to read a .obj file and render it in wire frame mode.
I had already read the .obj file (correctly - i believe) that i want to render. But i am having some problems... It is suppose to be in wire frame but instead... (image bellow)

[image: my output]

Here is the code:

```
    public void render(GL gl){
    float xMiddle = (m.getXVertexMax() + m.getXVertexMin())/2;
    float yMiddle = (m.getYVertexMax() + m.getYVertexMin())/2;
    float zMiddle = (m.getZVertexMax() + m.getZVertexMin())/2;

    gl.glScalef(1/(m.getXVertexMax() - m.getXVertexMin()), 1, 1);
    gl.glScalef(1, 1/(m.getYVertexMax() - m.getYVertexMin()), 1);
    gl.glScalef(1, 1, 1/(m.getZVertexMax() - m.getZVertexMin()));

    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glPolygonMode(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL.GL_LINES);
        for(int i = 0; i < m.faces.size(); i++ ){
            Vector3f n1 = m.normals.get(m.faces.get(i).getNormalIndices()[0] - 1); 
            Vector3f v1 = m.vertices.get(m.faces.get(i).getVertexIndices()[0] - 1);
            gl.glVertex3f(v1.x - xMiddle, v1.y - yMiddle, v1.z - zMiddle);
            gl.glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);


            Vector3f n2 = m.normals.get(m.faces.get(i).getNormalIndices()[1] - 1); 
            Vector3f v2 = m.vertices.get(m.faces.get(i).getVertexIndices()[1] - 1);
            gl.glVertex3f(v2.x - xMiddle, v2.y - yMiddle, v2.z - zMiddle);
            gl.glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);




            Vector3f n3 = m.normals.get(m.faces.get(i).getNormalIndices()[2] - 1); 
            Vector3f v3 = m.vertices.get(m.faces.get(i).getVertexIndices()[2] - 1);
            gl.glVertex3f(v3.x - xMiddle, v3.y - yMiddle, v3.z - zMiddle);
            gl.glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);

        }
    }
    gl.glEnd(); 
}
```

NOTE: Vector3f in the code, is a data structure that i made.

I have tried everything i could find but still, it wont render the image as wire frame! :-/

Can anyone give a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
{
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glPolygonMode(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL.GL_LINES);
    ...
```

*Very* few GL commands are valid inside a [`glBegin()/glEnd()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml) block:

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd.
>   The commands are
>   **glVertex, glColor, glSecondaryColor, glIndex, glNormal, glFogCoord, glTexCoord, glMultiTexCoord, glVertexAttrib, glEvalCoord, glEvalPoint,
>   glArrayElement, glMaterial, and glEdgeFlag.** Also, it is acceptable
>   to use glCallList or glCallLists to execute display lists that include
>   only the preceding commands.
>   **If any other GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd, the error flag is set and the command is ignored.**

`glEnable()` and `glPolygonMode()` are not on that list.

Move them outside your `glBegin()` block.

---

```
    gl.glVertex3f(v1.x - xMiddle, v1.y - yMiddle, v1.z - zMiddle);
    gl.glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
```

Wrong way around.  You want normal, *then* vertex:

```
    gl.glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
    gl.glVertex3f(v1.x - xMiddle, v1.y - yMiddle, v1.z - zMiddle);
```

`glNormal()` only sets the current normal, `glVertex()` is what actually sends that down the pipeline.

Comment: Also he use `glEnable` and `glPolygonMode` within the `glBegin` and `glEnd`, that is probably also a part of the problem not being rendered in wireframe.